# Fold expression vs compile recursion

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, sfinae, fold-expression

In `c++17` we have fold expression which can greatly simplify code that could otherwise be implemented using compiler-recursion and SFINAE or overloading.
For example, in the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template<typename ...Args>
void printer(Args&&... args) {
  (std::cout << ... << args) << '\n';
}

void printer_cpp11() { }

template <typename First, typename ...Args>
void printer_cpp11(First&& first, Args&&... args)
{
  std::cout << first;
  printer_cpp11(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main()
{
  printer(3, 4, "hello");

  std::cout << std::endl;

  printer_cpp11(3, 4, "hello");

  return 0;
}
```

the `c++17` function `printer` (taken from [cpp reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold)) does exactly the same job as its `c++11` version `printer_cpp11`.

At compile-time, several overloads of the function `printer_cpp11` are generated, whereas a single function `printer` is needed using fold expression.

Is there an advantage in terms of performance in using fold expressions over the `c++11`-style? Or can one assume that the compiler inlines all the overloads of `printer_cpp11`, creating code with equivalent performance?

Comment: By `printer(std::forward<Args>(args)...);` I think you mean `printer_cpp11(std::forward<Args>(args)...);`, right?

Comment: i think `printer_cpp11` should call itself, not the `printer`

Comment: Assumptions cannot be done, but why don't you profile it.

Comment: @L.F. sure, fixed the typo

Comment: `printer_cpp11` will cause compiler to recursively instantiate `sizeof…(Args)` different template functions - this is a common case of template bloat and slow compilation times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both versions would lead to the same codegen due to inlining, so run-time performance is exactly the same: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/VIHTvZ (code cleaned of streams clutter).

However, compilation times and memory usage are expected to be way better with fold expressions than with recursive instantiations, and because of that, fold expression are generally preferred. Not to mention they are also provide for cleaner and easier to reason about code.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to @SergeyA's answer you can alleviate the need for the recursion and the empty function in the c++11 version by doing something like...

```
template <typename ...Args>
void printer_cpp11_norecursion( Args&&... args)
{
  using do_ = int[];
  do_{0,
    (std::cout << args,0)...
  };
}
```

Which should generate the same results as both of the other versions (https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/hyAyiz) with possibly better compile times on c++11.

Comment: Thanks, it is the first time I see this syntax. You are initializing an array of ```int``` with 0s, discarding the results of the call to ```cout```, correct?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will create a new instance of **printer** for each call with different arguments and in the function will unfold the **operator<<** calls:

https://godbolt.org/z/Zz9Ik9

You can also see what happens here: https://cppinsights.io/

But ultimately - measuring will reveal if it leads to a performance gain.